# Swift's "if let" equivalent in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

What would be "if let" equivalent in Objective C? The example snippet I want to convert to Objective C is below;

```
if let pfobjects = images as? [PFObject] {
    if pfobjects.count > 0 {
        var imageView: PFImageView = PFImageView()
        imageView.file = pfobjects[0] as! PFFile
        imageView.loadInBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's much easier to help you if you format your code properly, so we can understand it. I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: what do you mean? `if let` unwraps an optional, there's no optionals in Objective-C. One does not simply declare optionals in Objective-C [insert Boromir]

Comment: `if let` is a special structure in Swift that allows you to check if an Optional holds a value. No need to use it in Objective C

Comment: and by the way, why learn Objective-C using Swift tutorials? I mean you could learn it using Objective-C tutorials, right?

Comment: I'm with @lascort.  If you want to learn Objective-C, Swift is not the way to do it.

Comment: Watching Swift videos is not the best way to learn Objective-C, but this is a reasonable, clearly-stated question for someone who already knows Swift and is learning Objective-C. There's no reason to downvote or close it.

Comment: @lascort Objective-C _does_ have optionals, by default even.  **In Objective-C, every variable typed to an object is optional.**  The only types that are nor optional in Objective-C are C-style value types.  Swift didn't improve on Objective-C with optionals, it did so with the addition of _non-optionals_, and many of Swift's constructs revolve around the idea of _“at this point in the code, I know I definitely have the object I think I have”_.

Answer (score 7):

There's no direct equivalent to `if let` in Objective-C, because `if let` does Swift-specific things (unwrapping optionals and rebinding identifiers) that don't have direct equivalents in Objective-C.

Here's a nearly equivalent of your Swift code:

```
if (images != nil) {
    NSArray<PFObject *> *pfobjects = (id)images;
    if (pfobjects.count > 0) {
        PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
        assert([pfobjects[0] isKindOfClass:[PFFile class]]);
        imageView.file = (PFFile *)pfobjects[0];
        [imageView loadInBackground];
    }
}
```

But this Objective-C code won't verify that `images` only contains instances of `PFObject`, and should successfully create an image view as long as `pfobjects[0]` is a `PFFile`. Your Swift code will do nothing (create no image view) if `images` contains any non-`PFObject` elements.

Comment: That is called a “lightweight generic” and is a recent addition to Objective-C. Prior to last June, you would not bother declaring another array because both `pfobjects` and `images` would just be type `NSArray *`.

Comment: The difference is that in Objective-C the `images != nil` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSPredicate to verify the array contains only instances of `PFObject`:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [PFObject class]];
NSInteger numberThatArePFObjects = [images filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p].count;
if(numberThatArePFObjects && numberThatArePFObjects == images.count){
    // certain that images only contains instances of PFObject.
}
```

If however you weren't working with an array but a single object then it is simpler:

```
if([image isKindOfClass:[PFObject class]]){
    // certain that image is a valid PFObject.
}
```

Or if you wanted a new variable:

```
PFObject* obj = nil;
if([image isKindOfClass:[PFObject class]] && (obj = image)){
    // certain that obj is a valid PFObject.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
NSArray<PFObject *> *pfobjects;
if ([images isKindOfClass: [NSArray<PFObject> class]] && (pfobjects = images)) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want three things simultaneously. Let's split them:

1. `variable as? OtherType` is possible, but erases type, because it returns `id`. Implementation is as easy as a category on `NSObject` class, so it becomes `NSArray *array = [jsonDict[@"objects"] ifKindOfClass:NSArray.class]`.

Implementation

```
@interface NSObject (OptionalDowncast)
- (id)ifKindOfClass:(__unsafe_unretained Class)clazz;
@end
@implementation NSObject (OptionalDowncast)
- (id)ifKindOfClass:(__unsafe_unretained Class)clazz {
    return [self isKindOfClass:clazz] ? self : nil;
}
@end
```

2. `if let` is also possible in Objective-C if type is known, so it cannot be combined with previous thing. Easiest way is: `for(NSArray *array = [self getItems]; array != nil; array = nil) { ... }`, but if you want to use `else` branch, it gets a bit more complex. I have made [SwiftyObjC](https://github.com/ReDetection/SwiftyObjC) pod for that, please take a look
3. Check generic template is not possible during type cast in Objective-C, thus you can cast to `NSArray`, but you can't cast to `NSArray<PFObject>`

I don't see iterations over your array: With all that being said, I think best example is (assuming images is an array already):

```
for(PFFile *file = [images.firstObject ifKindOfClass:PFFile.class]; file != nil; file = nil) {
  imageView.file = file;
  [imageView loadInBackground];
}
```

If you need to also iterate over it:

```
for(id object in images) {
  for(PFFile *file = [object ifKindOfClass:PFFile.class]; file != nil; file = nil) {
     //operate on file
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Objective-C++ in place of Objective-C. In this you can use the next define:

```
#define let const auto
```

Note: it is not the same exactly (Swift has wrapped values, ...) but it makes the work easier.

And through of this define you can use it of this way:

```
if (let pfobjects = images) {
    if (pfobjects.count > 0 {
        let imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.file = pfobjects[0];
        imageView loadInBackground();
    }
}
```

To convert your Objective-C class in Objective-C++ class you only must change the extension of implementation file of .m to .mm